# INSERT INTO multiple tables with a single SQL statement, preserving AutoNumber

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

`Payments` consists of a single Autonumber field - `PaymentID`. `

`PaymentsMain` contains two fields - `MainID`, and `PaymentID`. It is joined to `Payments` on `PaymentsMain.PaymentID = Payments.PaymentID`.

How can I insert a single value into `PaymentsMain.MainID`, and have a new corresponding record added to `Payments` with the AutoNumber calculated into `Payments.PaymentID`, and that calculated Autonumber used as the value for `PaymentsMain.PaymentID'?

I imagine this is possible if I manually generate the `PaymentID` - some sort of running sum based on the `MainID`s added to the initial maximum value of the `PaymentID`, but I am wondering if this can be done using the Autonumbers alone.

**Edit**

The relationships are as follows:[image: Relationships]

**Edit**

If it is possible to specify that Access should insert the `DEFAULT` value for the `PaymentID`, that would also work.

Comment: To insert into multiple tables in a single statement, you need a stored procedure.

Comment: In ms access, you'll need to code this up yourself in vba (or similar). You'll have to simulate a "transaction" - won't be perfect but should be pretty robust.

Comment: @Gabe - Does Access support SPs?

Comment: Please show your create-table statements with any foreign keys.

Comment: Access does not have SPs or triggers.  Access has client-side VB modules.

Comment: @sasfrom I was originally using DAO for this. This is part of an HTA application, which connects to the database via DAO, and there ended up being too many connections for the database to handle.

Comment: @Tim I initially used the designer. Is there an Access equivalent to MySQL `SHOW TABLES`, or the like?

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is an INSERT trigger on one of your tables.

Comment: Go to the Relationships window and you can describe them. You'll probably have to create the create table statements yourself from the GUI representation of the relationships. I think Access does not have a way to generate that statement as SQL Server and other database engines do.

Comment: @Gabe And Access pre-2010 does not have triggers either.

Comment: Payments seems to be an unnecessary table. It serves no purpose.

Comment: You're right. It's there for "historical reasons" and I don't have time right now to go through the entire app and remove it.

Comment: You didn't mention what version of Access you are using. Is it something earlier than 2010?

Comment: @Gabe The database needs to stay compatible with previous versions of Access.

Comment: Without triggers this can't be done is a single SQL statement, at least, not that I can see.

Comment: @Zev Spitz wants an insert into the child table (PaymentsMain) to create the parent table row in Payments (if it does not already exist). But because of the foreign-key relationship, Payments row must exist BEFORE PaymentsMain row can be created. This kludge would have to be done in VB code in Access. Access SQL cannot do it. As sasfrog indicated above.

Comment: If Payments is otiose, and is not used in queries, the fk relationship could be removed, and Payments could be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following:

- It is possible to insert into fields from multiple tables, if the target of the `INSERT` statement is a saved query.
- An Autonumber field can be inserted into.
- It is possible to simulate an Autonumber sequence in SQL.

The first step is to create a saved query as follows (named `target` in this case):

```
SELECT PaymentsMain.MainID, PaymentsMain.PaymentID, Payments.PaymentID
FROM PaymentsMain 
INNER JOIN Payments ON PaymentsMain.PaymentID = Payments.PaymentID;
```

Then calculate the maximum AutoNumber currently in the database (in this case 1626).

Finally, the `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO target (MainID, PaymentsMain.PaymentID, Payments.PaymentID)
SELECT MainID, NewPaymentID, NewPaymentID
FROM (
    SELECT Main.MainID, Sum(1) + 1626 AS NewPaymentID
    FROM Main 
    LEFT JOIN Main AS m2 ON Main.MainID>=m2.MainID
    GROUP BY Main.MainID
)
```

(This assumes that the Autonumber is sequential, and not random).